# Setting focus on an MUI Input component when clicking outside its area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating an application with ReactJS and Material UI. I have an Input component inside a FormControl component. I would like to set the focus on the Input component when the user clicks in the FormControl (but still outside the Input component). How can this be achieved?

I have tried with refs but I was not able to do it:

```
<FormControl
    onClick={this.textInput.focus()}
    style={{ display: 'block', cursor: 'text' }}
>
<Input
  error={this.props.error}
  disabled={this.props.disabled}
  ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
/>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: I get: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `material-ui`, but I think there are two problems here. Firstly, your value for `onClick` is not a function, so this will call `focus` when the component gets instantiated, on a ref that is not defined yet. You can fix this by wrapping the call: `() => this.textInput.focus()` (or create a method/instance property for it.)

Secondly, `material-ui` wraps the `Input` component in a `withStyles` higher-order component, and when you use `ref`, it refers to the wrapped component, which doesn't have a `focus` method. Instead, you can use the `inputRef` prop, which creates a ref to the actual `input` DOM element. (see https://material-ui-next.com/customization/api/#internal-components)

This code should work:

```
..
  <FormControl
    onClick={() => this.textInput.focus()}
    style={{ display: 'block', cursor: 'text' }}
  >
    <Input
      error={this.props.error}
      disabled={this.props.disabled}
      inputRef={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
    />
  </FormControl>
..
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with context and the way the click event is handled in the `FormControl` element.

Try this instead:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.setFocus = this.setFocus.bind(this);
}
setFocus() {
  this.textInput.focus();
}
render() {
  return(
    <FormControl
      onClick={this.setFocus}
      style={{ display: 'block', cursor: 'text' }}
    >
      <Input
        error={this.props.error}
        disabled={this.props.disabled}
        ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an annotation, is valid to remember that if you are using some sort of animation, it's possible that your input has'nt been created yet at the mounting of the main component. In this case, a `setTimeout` with a timer bigger than the animation time can help.